# Modify existing JBehave Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jbehave

I'm using JBehave plugin for Eclipse:

```
  JBehave Eclipse   1.0.0.20140605-0717 org.jbehave.eclipse.feature.feature.group   null
```

My project is quite large and is suffering from a problem when you open a story file it lags on every keystroke and generally just makes Eclipse grind to a halt on occasion.

After Googling I see it has been brought up here - https://github.com/Arnauld/jbehave-eclipse-plugin/issues/54

Following the trail it seems there was a fix that was never submitted upstream - https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-eclipse/pull/12/commits/6d6458bd6c69249e34b94f5c8ce7f0b1a7759fb6

How can I build the plugin with this fix in?  I can't find any instructions.

Comment: The `BUILD.markdown` file on the [main page](https://github.com/Arnauld/jbehave-eclipse-plugin) appears to contain build instructions

Comment: Thanks, I'll try